# Adobe Flash. How to play animation till end without interrupting using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, adobe

I'm creating flash game. Here are 3 different attacks (*label names:* `attack1, attack2, attack3`) with different animations (keyboard bind z, x, c).

**Problem**

For example If I use attack1 (by clicking "z") It shows animation with ~100 frames (animation lasts 3 seconds), but while during animation I click attack2 (x) It cancels attack1 animation and start playing attack2 animation. I need to make that when during animation It can't be interrupted by using other animation.

I have created an array:

```
var codes:Array = new Array(0, 90, 88, 67);
var attack:Number = 0;
```

This is my key_down function:

```
    private function key_down(event:KeyboardEvent)
    {
        if (event.keyCode == 90)
        {

            if (attack > 0)
            {
                return;
            }// don't interrupt other attack
            for (var c in codes)
            {
                if (codes[c] == event.keyCode)
                {
                    attack = c;
                    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack" + attack);
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 88)
        {
            if (attack > 0)
            {
                return;
            }// don't interrupt other attack
            for (c in codes)
            {
                if (codes[c] == event.keyCode)
                {
                    attack = c;
                    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack" + attack);
                }
            }
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 67)
        {
            if (attack > 0)
            {
                return;
            }// don't interrupt other attack
            for (c in codes)
            {
                if (codes[c] == event.keyCode)
                {
                    attack = c;
                    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack" + attack);
                }
                else
                {
                    Hero.gotoAndStop("attack" + attack);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

When I use this, it not interrupting the same attacks animation, I mean If I use Attack1 by clicking "x" I can click "x" again and animation not interrupting, but still interrupting by clicking other button "z" or "c".

As I understand in timeline last animation's frame I need to add something like

```
attack=0;
MovieClip(parent).gotoAndStop("stay");
```

That after animation played attack will be set to 0 and continued playing "stay" animation, but **I got error**: `Access of undefined property attack.`

Answer (score 0):

I cannot illustrate your problem. But as far as I understand you want to make animation without a hitch. In that case you need to do basic **open** - **close** animation for your character.

e.g. like that ;

**1 - 30** frames for character attack animation. That means "open" animation.

**30 - 60** frames when you faced with attack against then you need to do run "close" animation.

```
function attack():void
{
            if(currentState == "Attack")
            {
                currentState = "Attack";
                timelineAnimation.gotoAndPlay("Attack_InAnimation");
            }
            else if(currentState == "CounterAttack")
            {
                currentState = "CounterAttack";
                timelineAnimation.gotoAndPlay("Attack_OutAnimation");
            }
  }
```

I hope this is useful for you. This is just my approach.

Comment: I don't know If you understood my problem, I will try to explain. If I click "z" button It starts attack1 animation, If I click "x" button - It starts attack2 animation and If I click "c" button It starts attack3 animation. After "z" button is clicked It starts attack 1 animation for ~3 seconds, I need to make that It will be impossible to interrupt It by clicking other buttons (x,c).

Comment: In Hero timeline I have keyframes labeled attack1, attack2, attack3, jumping etc... Here is screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bGnUD.png

Comment: Well, actually it is same approach as I said before. You have to cache your current animation for later destroy or close them.